# VBA, copy columns with formulas to new worksheet as values

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to take a sheet that has vlookups and paste them as values into my new sheet.

```
  ws3.Columns(4).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sample File").Columns(1)
```

I get REF error after doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try it like this...

```
ws3.Columns(4).Copy
Sheets("Sample File").Columns(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```